# how to set the token in database for user never expire even after browser closed?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have been using codeigniter3 . I would like to set cookie token in database. so that even after the browser closed session will not expire. based on the token stored how to achieve this?

```
  $cookie = array(
        'name' => 'token',
        'value' => generateRandomString() ,
        'expire' => '1209600',
        'domain' => domain() ,
        'path' => '/'
    );

    set_cookie($cookie);
```

Comment: use *Cookies*? ->[Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php)?

Comment: could you tell me how to use cookie that never expire evern after browser closed

Comment: i think you have mistaken cookies with sessions, Sessions expire when the Browser is closed or the User leaves the Site, they are on the Server. Cookies although are saved on the client, even after the Browser is closed

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, you are mistaken between cookies and sessions;

- Sessions are server side only, they end at the browsing session is terminated.
- Cookies are machine stored values that are kept until your time limit.

For example, if you have this code:

```
session_start(); // Start the session
$_SESSION['username'] = "Sam Swift 웃"; // Set a value into the session
isset($_COOKIE['username']) ?: setcookie("username", $_SESSION['username'], 0); // A cookie that will last forever
```

The `$_SESSION['username']` value will be destroyed when the browser closes as the server holds it while the browser is open, whereas the cookie with the name `username`, will be held forever as the time limit is set to 0.

If you use Google Chrome, try looking at this [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg) which let's you view cookies that are set for a site.

I hope this helps you.

**Notes for thought:**

- Cookies take a resend of the data to be processed by the browser, so when you first set them, resend the page to the server and it'll appear